# Prepaid SIM cards in Argentina — expiration and roaming?

Tags: cellphones, argentina, south-america

For my last several visits to Argentina, I've bought a SIM card and charged it as needed for data only for my cell.

I have a Movistar SIM from my trip in February.

1) Do these expire?  Can I charge it when I go again in November or do I need a new one?

2) I am also traveling to Brazil and Uruguay.  I assume this kind of prepaid plan will not roam.  Is that the case?  If it does roam, are the charges very high?

I am basically between getting a global sim ($60 for 1GB of data) or trying to use the Movistar SIM I have.

Comment: Any reason not to get a new sim card at each country/visit/airport?

Comment: I am on a cruise and only in some countries a day or two.  I don't want to spend my time running around trying to find a SIM (I don't speak much Spanish), trying to get it to work, etc. for such a short period.

Answer (score 2):

They do expire in about six months to a year. I have asked Movistar repeatedly about this but the answers were all over the place. Last card I bought I didn't use from Jan 10 to July 20, and it still worked; I think, though, that I recharged it remotely before the six months would kick in by July 10.

Other Movistar cards that I didn't use for a longer time were deactivated before a year. On the "interesting" side, even after the sim was no longer active and the number had been given to another user, I was still able to see the call logs on Movistar's page. Talk about bad IT (not that I expect the other carriers to be better at this).

As for roaming, it didn't roam in Canada nor in Chile, so I assume it doesn't anywhere.